# Resolution is changing in Google Earth Engine output

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

GEE is changing the spatial resolution when I sum a feature collection and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is some example code.

```
data = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR").filterDate("2023-01-01","2023-12-31")
image = data.first()
image.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()

image2 = data.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
image2.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()
```

For `image`, the spatial resolution is correct. `image2` is much coarser.

What can I do to maintain the spatial resolution of the summed feature collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projection information is lost when multiple images are combined. To preserve it, you can use [`setDefaultProjection`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-setdefaultprojection) to restore the original projection after reducing:

```py
data = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR").filterDate("2023-01-01","2023-12-31")
image = data.first()
image.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()

image2 = data.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).setDefaultProjection(image.projection())
image2.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()
```